# Back up /home from a live CD

Tags: backup, home-directory

I need to back up the /home to a different location. How to do it? `/home` is in a seperate parition with '/home` folders of other distros as well? I need to backup them all before i do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If you boot an Ubuntu live session, then the home partition will be shown in Nautilus, so you can just click to mount it. Then you can copy the folders elsewhere like you do with any other folder.

Comment: You should be able to backup your /home partition (even from other distros) to a portable HDD (assuming you're doing so to reformat the HDD with the /home). Once the drive is mounted in the live session it's just a simple click and drag to the portable HDD or other location if you prefer.

Comment: But, “/home” directory will have hardlinks, softlinks, files and nested directories, a regular copy (cp) or drag and drop may not do the job completely.

Comment: use `sudo rsync -a <source> <destination>` or run a [backup solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools) then...